# select most recent comment on a table when ID is not unique

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i have a table that looks like this:
(using Sql-server 2012)

```
ID------------DAY----------HOUR--COMMENT

00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 14:41 | Creaci¢n de Pedido UD3503-0000001 ==> UD4003            
00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 11:52 | Se di¢ de alta el documento: UD4003-0000003                                     
00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 11:42 | Asignaci¢n de t‚cnico: MANUEL REGALADO                                          
00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 11:42 | Cambio de fecha y hora programa                   
00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 11:40 | SE PROGRAMARA POSTERIOR MENTE                      
00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 11:39 | PRUEBA NUMERO SERIE OS  ANALISIS
```

i managed to order the results by date and hour in a way i can see the last comment on top but the problem is that since my ID isnt unique i dont know how can i select the latest comment.

my query:

```
select * from
(
select gdoshistorial.c1 as ID,max(gdoshistorial.c3) as [DAY],
max(gdoshistorial.c4) as [TIME], gdoshistorial.c6 AS COMMENT from gdos   
left join gdoshistorial on GDOSHISTORIAL.c1 = gdos.c1
where gdos.c1 = gdoshistorial.c1 and gdoshistorial.c1 = '00050064'
group by GDOSHISTORIAL.c1,GDOSHISTORIAL.c6
)v

order by [ID],[DAY],[TIME] desc
```

please help me to find a way to select the first row and ignore the  repeated id's
desired result example:

```
ID------------DAY----------HOUR--COMMENT

00050064 | 2015-09-30  | 14:41 | Creaci¢n de Pedido UD3503-0000001 ==> UD4003
```

instead of getting lots of comments from the same id i just want to see the most recent one.

Comment: Please include an example of what you want the results to look like.

Comment: Do you have date and time in separate columns? What data type are they? Can you post the data structure and not only your query results? Why on Earth are fields called c1, c2, c3?????

Comment: date is datetime, hour is char(5)

Comment: Those tables were designed by the Devil himself.

Comment: I know they suck, didnt made them myself Q-Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, date, hour, comment from
(
select row_number() over(partition by id, day order by hour desc) as rn,
* from gdoshistorial ) t
where rn = 1
```

You can use `row_number` to get the latest information for each day and id.

Note: the query above would give you latest comment for each day. If you need only the latest comment, no matter the day,
change

```
row_number() over(partition by id, day order by hour desc) as rn
```

to

```
row_number() over(partition by id order by day desc, hour desc) as rn
```

Comment: I think you have to first merge day and time and then order by that.

Comment: ill try your answer be trying your answer. thanks for the fast reply c:

Comment: I think you should only `partition by id` and `order by day desc, hour desc` other wise you get the latest comment of each day instead of the latest comment of that ID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT gdoshistorial.c1 AS ID
        ,max(gdoshistorial.c3) AS [DAY]
        ,max(gdoshistorial.c4) AS [TIME]
        ,gdoshistorial.c6 AS COMMENT
    FROM gdos
    LEFT JOIN gdoshistorial ON GDOSHISTORIAL.c1 = gdos.c1
    WHERE gdos.c1 = gdoshistorial.c1
        AND gdoshistorial.c1 = '00050064'
    GROUP BY GDOSHISTORIAL.c1
        ,GDOSHISTORIAL.c6
    ) v
ORDER BY 
     [DAY] DESC
    ,[TIME] DESC
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt explain on my question that i wanted to use that query for all the id's not just the "00050064" one. thats why i havent used the Top 1 but thanks for your interest on answering me.

Comment: I see, the question say `AND gdoshistorial.c1 = '00050064'`so I guess you was using as a filter result